# Generate parameter list with userdefined types at runtime (using C#)

Tags: dynamic, methods, runtime

As part of my project, I am trying to build a web UI where user will select a method and pass the values. My program should be able to call the method dynamically and build a parameter list on runtime to pass it to the method.

I have created a comma separated list (string) of key and value pairs. This key/value pair is nothing but the parameter name and value of my method (methodname stored in a variable). Example: `string params = "ID:123;Name:Garry;Address:addressObject;AddressLine:108 Plaza Lane;City:Avenel;State:NJ;Zip:07001;"`. Where ID and Name are simple string varaibles while Address is user defined type. What follows after Address i.e. AddressLine, City, State and Zip is elements of Address object. And my method definition is

```
public string GetInfo(string ID, string Name, Address addressObject)
{
  //return something;
}
```

I am dynamically calling the method (GetInfo) that is stored in sMethodName variable using DynamicProxy like :

```
string sMethodName = "GetInfo";
object result = (object) proxy.CallMethod(sMethodName, arguments);
```

Challenge is how to pass the argument list dynamically? Till now I am just able to extract the values from the csv variable into NamedValueCollection. Here is the code:

```
public static void StoreParameterValues(string param)
{
    nvc = new NameValueCollection();
    param = param.TrimEnd(';');
    string[] parameters = param.Split(new char[] { ';' });
    foreach (string val in parameters)
    {
        string[] keyValue = val.Split(new char[] { ':' });
        nvc.Add(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
    }
}
```

..and here is the code that tries to build the parameter:

```
string methodName = "GetInfo";
DynamicProxyFactory factory = new DynamicProxyFactory("http://../myservice.svc"); 
string sContract = "";
foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in factory.Endpoints)
{
    sContract = endpoint.Contract.Name;
}
DynamicProxy proxy = factory.CreateProxy(sContract);
string[] values = null;
// Create the parameter list
object[] arguments = new object[nvc.Count];
int i = -1;
foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
{
    values = nvc.GetValues(key);
    foreach (string value in values)
    {
        arguments[++i] = value;
    }
}
object result = (object) proxy.CallMethod(methodName, arguments);
```

The above code works if I have simple primitive types but not sure how can I build the logic for any other userdefined types. How can I create a object dynamically of type stored in a variable? Not sure if I was able to put my question correctly. I hope so :)

Edit: 01/19/2011: Applied the suggestion from Chris - using Reflection instead of ComponentModel.
I have converted the code to make it more generic. This works now for all primitive and custom types (resursion). Code snippet below:

```
private object BuildParameterList(Type type)
{
    object item = new object();

    item = Activator.CreateInstance(type);            

    PropertyInfo[] propArray = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);

    for (int i = 0; i < propArray.Length; i++)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = (PropertyInfo)propArray[i];

        ////Check for custom type
        if (IsCustomType(pi.PropertyType))
        {
            object item1 = BuildParameterList(pi.PropertyType);
            pi.SetValue(item, item1, null);
        }
        else
        {
            if (property.ContainsKey(pi.Name))
            {                                               
                pi.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(property[pi.Name], pi.PropertyType), null);
            }
        }
    }            
    return item;
}
```

But if one of the property is Color (I just tested with Color type, will fail with other system types aswell-i guess), then it fails at the following line. Not sure how to handle system types - Color or something similar.

```
pi.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(property[pi.Name], pi.PropertyType), null);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with WCF or web services?

Comment: John, the program accepts a WCF service and using reflection I display the methods and the method parameters. Once user selects the method and enter the parameter values, I want to dynamically call the method with passed values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not find what types are expected by the method, by inspecting its `ParameterInfo`s:

```
endpoint.Contract.ContractType.GetMethod(methodName).GetParameters();
```

and then instantiating the custom types using:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(parameterType);
```

Comment: Chris, thanks for the prompt response. I was able to instantiate the custom type using your suggestion of Activaor.CreateInstance. Now I will try to initialize the individual attributes of the custom type and will get back if there is an issue.

Comment: Chris, I tried object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(parameterType); but how will I access the public properties and initialize them with my values so that I can pass this custom object to my method call?

Comment: From your comment on the question, it appears you have already obtained the PropertyInfos for the object's properties, so can't you now just call SetValue on them?

Comment: Chirs, I just edited the post to explain what I did till now. Yes, I am able to get the list of properties for the object. And tried to call SetValue. It worked for primitive types - string, int etc but not worked yet for "system" types like Color. Eventually I also need to setvalue for another custom type within :(

Comment: You seem to be trying to use the System.ComponentModel types which work with metadata (design-time) properties, but if I've understood your problem correctly, you should be using System.Reflection types i.e. calling Type.GetProperties() and PropertyInfo.SetValue().

Comment: Chris, I was able to convert the code to use just Reflection instead of ComponentModel. But still not sure how to handle the types like Color? See my edited code in the original post. I get error at the following line: pi.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(property[pi.Name], pi.PropertyType), null);
Also, tried to type case explicitly like: pi.SetValue(item, System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Red"), null) but it didn't work either. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ..also, I receive the following error when I use 
?pi.SetValue(item, System.Drawing.Color.Red, null);
The type 'System.Drawing.Color' exists in both 'System.Drawing.dll' and 'htducg7h.dll'